# DB2 restore db from backup

Tags: db2, backup, restore

I'm trying restore db2 database from backup by this command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE DEKAT02B FROM "/home/db2inst1/.ibm/db2/desktop/" TAKEN AT 20180104111638 WITHOUT PROMPTING
```

And I had this error:

```
`Caused by: com.ibm.tivoli.remoteaccess.RemoteAccessAuthException: CTGRI0000E Could not establish a connection to the target machine with the authorization credentials that were provided.`
```

Im sure that I enter right credentials.
Thanks.

Comment: There are many hits on google for CTGRI0000E.  Have you done any research to solve the issue by yourself?

Comment: Yeap, im trying restore from db2 console but also had error, but like this:SQL1035N  The operation failed because the specified database cannot be
connected to in the mode requested.

Comment: SQL1035N  may result from the failed restore. You need to abort the restore correctly. Refer to the Db2 knowledge center for your version of Db2 for the 'restore database' command to see the syntax for aborting a previously failed restore.